# Second CSS stylesheet taking priority over the first one

Tags: html, css

I have read a lot about the CSS priorities and !important declarations, but still I see something strange happening in [this](http://glamourina.pl) site.

The theme came with one main style.css file and several other .css files, that basically change only the colors. So that one theme could be in yellow, pink, white, etc.
Since I don't need all of them, I am trying to merge the file bianco.css with the style.css in order to have only 1 file.

I have already merged (deleted from bianco.css) a lot of classes, and all is working fine. But still I need to merge a lot of them.

Now I am struggling with the following.

In the main style.css I have

```
body{font-family: pt-serif, sans-serif, Georgia, Helvetica, Arial;font-size:13px;background:#fff;line-height:154%!important;}
```

And in the bianco.css I have

```
body{background-color:#FFF!important;font-size:13px;line-height:154%;}
```

I know that if a specific property is selected in two different files, then the latest one is the one that will be applied. But if there is only 1 property declared, then only this one will be chosen and applied. It doesn't matter in which file it is, the important is for the filed to be loaded.

So if I try to remove that whole line from the bianco.css file, then the fonts in the site get bigger. This is strange. The file style.css is loaded and I can see the `font-size:13px;` loaded in the Chrome developers tool, but it's ignored for some reason. And I don't see any other style rool that may be overriding the font size.

Does anybody know what's going on here? What is making the style.css rule to be ignored?

Comment: check this http://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: Both font-size and line-height are the same in both stylesheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the 13px from bianco.css it takes style from some slideshow.css and this is the corrosponding line

```
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,code,del,dfn,em,img,q,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,dialog,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section 
{ margin:0; 
padding:0; 
border:0; 
font-weight:inherit;
 font-style:inherit;
 font-size:100%;
 font-family:inherit;
 vertical-align:baseline; 
}
```

this is the reason why fonts get bigger try editing/removing this. it will accept style.css 13 px font size

Comment: Thank you. That was the solution. Please help me understand. I thought `font-size:100%;` means: 100% of the size that was set before, so 13px. This is why I thought that it can't influence the code that will be loaded below. Why `font-size:100%;` is enlarging the font instead than leaving it the same?

Comment: Font size to 100% is default browser specific font size which is around i guess 14 px. not sure . that's y it was increasing marginally